# how to add custom Style in npm mydatepicker?

Tags: css, node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

how to add custom Style in **npm mydatepicker**?
I am using this code:

```html
<my-date-picker [options]="myDatePickerOptions" (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)"></my-date-picker>
```

How to change its background-color and height width ?

Comment: One way is to inspect from browser and find out which element to set the styles and add css in your css file

Comment: I have used this way but it will set style on the all component. But I want only a particular DatePicker

Comment: Then wrap the above code inside div with some class or id and give styles using the wrapper id/class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use option to set custom values.

```
<input angular-mydatepicker [(ngModel)]="model" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" 
    #dp="angular-mydatepicker">
```

and use it like this : (Give it as string value)

```
import {IAngularMyDpOptions} from 'angular-mydatepicker';

export class MyApp {
    myDatePickerOptions: IAngularMyDpOptions = {
        selectorHeight: "232px",
        selectorWidth: "252px"
        // other options here
    }

    constructor() {}

}
```

You can refer https://github.com/kekeh/angular-mydatepicker/wiki/change-color-theme-of-datepicker to have custom color theme.

I hope this will help you in solving your issue.

Comment: Hello, I do have kinda the same issue, but that many years later the given link is deleted.
How do I add a custom style (i.e. "position; relative") to the date picker ?